# Find the clasification rate using different value of k

Tags: matlab, knn

I use KNN search to classify the testing data and find the classification rate.

Below is the matlab code: for example:

```
load fisheriris
x = meas(:,3:4); % x =all training data
y = [5 1.45;6 2;2.75 .75]; % y =3 testing data for 'versicolor' species

[n,d] = knnsearch(x,y,'k',1);   % find the nearest neighbors to three testing data

predicted_class=species(n);

true_class=[cellstr('versicolor'); cellstr('versicolor'); cellstr('versicolor')];

Classification_rate=100*sum(strcmp(predicted_class,true_class))/length(predicted_class);
```

However, the matlab code above just suitable for k=1,if i tried k=2 there was error using strcmp 'Inputs must be the same size or either one can be a scalar.' Is there anyway to modify the code??

Then,if i wanna test another species such as 'virginica',i need to take time to change the true_class from 'versicolor' to 'virginica',is there any ways to change it automatically?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the first part of your question. But for the second part you could just define a variable for both of the strings 'versicolor' and 'virginica', and then place a loop so that they change with each iteration:

```
Vars = {'versicolor','virginica'};
for i = 1:length(Vars);
    true_class = [cellstr(Vars{i}); cellstr(Vars{i}); cellstr(Vars{i})];
    Classification_rate{i} = 100*sum(strcmp(predicted_class,true_class))/length(predicted_class);
end
```

Comment: the classification rate have 2 answers if running your code,that means if the Vars=versicolor,the classification rate is 33.3(first ans),and if the Vars=virginica,the classification rite is 66.6(second ans).However, i need to get one result if i change the true_class.